# Match a string separated by slashes

Tags: regex

In the first sample I want to match `Mortal`

**Input 1:**

```
=Mortal
```

**Regex 1:**

```
=(.+)
```

**Output 1:**

```
MATCH 1
1.  [1-7]   `Mortal`
```

Works just as I want.

In the second sample, I want to match `Mortal` and `Combat`

**Input 2:**

```
=Mortal/Combat
```

**Regex 2:**

```
=(.+)\/(.+)
```

**Output 2:**

```
MATCH 1
1.  [1-7]   `Mortal`
2.  [8-14]  `Combat`
```

Works just as I want.

My problem is that I want a solution that does both.

If I use `=(.+)\/(.+)` on `=Mortal` it matches *nothing*.

If I use `=(.+)` on `=Mortal/Combat` it matches:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [1-14]  `Mortal/Combat`
```

Both are incorrect.

Tried to merge them together:

```
=((.+)\/(.+)|(.+))
```

Which matches:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [1-14]  `Mortal/Combat`
2.  [1-7]   `Mortal`
3.  [8-14]  `Combat`
```

Or:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [1-7]   `Mortal`
4.  [1-7]   `Mortal`
```

Definitely incorrect.

**Desired output should either be:**

```
MATCH 1
1.  [1-7]   `Mortal`
```

Or:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [1-7]   `Mortal`
2.  [8-14]  `Combat`
```

**Would also be cool** if it would be compatible with three slashes: `=Mortal/Combat/X` should become:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [0-6]   `Mortal`
2.  [7-13]  `Combat`
3.  [14-15] `X`
```

How can I achieve this?

I am using http://regex101.com to test the regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for all the three cases:

```
^=(.+)\/(.+)\/(.+)|=(.+)\/(.+)|=(.+)$
```

Explanation:

```
^                 # Assert position at the beginning of the line
=(.+)\/(.+)\/(.+) # Three slashes
|                 # OR
=(.+)\/(.+)       # Two slashes
|                 # OR
=(.+)             # No slashes
$                 # Assert position at the end of the line
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/bZ1fX5)

Answer (score 0):

[**Live demo**](http://regex101.com/r/rJ5zM7)

Try this:

```
=(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*)|=(.*)\/(.*)|=(.*)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=([^\/]+)\/?(.+)?
```

The ? make it optional. This select everything before / for the first group. The rest are optional

You can change the + with * if you want to match empty values also.

Generic with supporting any amount of /

```
=(([^\/]+)\/?)*
```

Just look in group two for the values